# Storing A hashmap in array and vice verse

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am Currently developing an application using firestore cloud as a back-end service. In addition, I want to store the hashmap values into an array and then passing it to the database. following code is what already achieved but still did not fit what I need.

*Model Class*

```
public class TripsInfoModel {
private String Country, Region, Balance, Stutas, updateDate, UserID;
List<String> TripsData;

public TripsInfoModel() {
}

public TripsInfoModel(String country, String region, String balance, String stutas, String updateDate, String userID,List<String> tripsData) {
    Country = country;
    Region = region;
    Balance = balance;
    Stutas = stutas;
    this.updateDate = updateDate;
    UserID = userID;
    TripsData = tripsData;


}



public String getCountry() {
    return Country;
}

public String getRegion() {
    return Region;
}

public String getBalance() {
    return Balance;
}

public String getStutas() {
    return Stutas;
}

public String getUpdateDate() {
    return updateDate;
}

public String getUserID() {
    return UserID;
}

public List<String> getTripsData() {
    return TripsData;
}
```

**Send data to fire-store function**

```
 String startDate = startPickDate.getText().toString().trim();
    String EndDate = endPickDate.getText().toString().trim();
    String Country = CountryName.getText().toString().trim();
    String CityNmae = mCity.getText().toString().trim();
    int Balance = Integer.parseInt(TripBalance.getText().toString());
    String Dsc = mDec.getText().toString().trim();

    HashMap <String, String>TripList = new HashMap<>();
    TripList.put("From",startDate);
    TripList.put("End",EndDate);
    TripList.put("Note",Dsc);

    String [] data = (String[]) TripList.values().toArray();
    List<String> TripsData = Arrays.asList(data);




    if (startDate.equals("") || EndDate.equals("")
            || Country.equals("") || CityNmae.equals("") || Balance <= 0 || Dsc.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(DateAndTime2.this, "Please identify  the date ,  or filed is missed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        TripsInfoModel addData = new TripsInfoModel(Country,CityNmae,Balance,"Available",CurrentTime,UID,TripsData);
        db.collection("TripsInfo").document(UID).collection("SeprateData").document()
                .set(addData).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(DateAndTime2.this, "Data has added successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });

    }
```

In addition, the attched snaphot is showing what I want really to achive 
[image: Triplist]

Comment: I can't tell from your description what exactly you expect the document to contain after your work is done. It looks to me you did exactly what you described - storing hashmap objects in an array.

Comment: but it gives null values, can you please check the attached snapshot(TripsList Structure), how I can store the data like that. for example, the index [0] stored values which are from: Airport, note: Note1, to: Hotel. Hope u get it by now

Comment: @DougStevenson ,

Comment: I don't understand your question.  It looks like you haven't even written any code that actually adds the data to Firestore.

Comment: I have edit the whole code, hope u get it by now @DougStevenson

Answer (score 1):

Once you receive the field data from the Cloud Firestore as a `HashMap`, map all the keys and values alternatively in an `Array` as shown below. All the **keys are in even number locations** and all the **values are in odd number locations**

```
   0       1       2       3      . . .   n-1      n         <--- Index

| Key1 | Value1 | Key2 | Value2 | . . . | Keyn | Valuen |    <--- Array
```

You can do this by using the `HashMap.keySet()` to get all the keys as a Set and then use the `HashMap.get(key)` to get the corresponding value. Feed it into the Array as shown and you are good to go.

Remember, `Keyk` will be at `Array[k-1]` and `Valuek` will be at `Array[k]`. For example, `Key7` will be at `Array[6]` and its corresponding value `Value7` will be at `Array[7]`

If you want a particular key and you do not know its index, just run a [Linear Search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linear-search/) on the Array to find the key and at the next index is its corresponding value.

To generate a `HashMap` from an `Array`, format the Array as shown above and use the `HashMap.put(key, value)`

The thing is, All HashMaps can be stored as an Array but storing an Array as a HashMap doesn't make sense at all times

**EDIT: Forgot to answer the adding to Firestore thing**

The `tripList` field shown in the image is an Array of HashMaps Just create an `Array` with `Object` datatype and load them with `HashMap`s as shown.

```
     0          1          2                  n
| HashMap0 | HashMap1 | HashMap2 | . . . | HashMapn |
```

Now, load this array into the Cloud Firestore through the following command

```
db.collection("TripsList").document(UID).update("tripList", HashMapArray);
```

Remember, there needs to be an array named `tripList` in Firestore to prevent getting errors

Hope this Helps..!

Comment: Your explanation is great but this thing can be performed during fetching the data . in my case I want to store the data as it shows in the attached image.

Comment: @Abdulmalek Please check out the updated Answer. I am not an expert in Firestore, I am more of a Realtime Database guy. So, I'm sorry if there are any minor errors in my answer. My main focus was to make you understand the process.

Comment: it is great things but how I can create an array with hashmap,

Comment: Try an `Object` Array. `HashMap<>` also falls under `Object` datatype. Also, try `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`.

Comment: @Abdulmalek If my answer was able to solve your problem, please consider upvoting & marking it as the solution..!